# I get an error when I try to install ROS on VMware fusion 12 pro

Tags: opencv, installation, ros, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to install ROS on my VMware fusion 12, but after updating the bash file as per the installation document, I get an error when I enter roscore in the terminal. The error seems to be that my VMware cannot ping itself. It also affected me using openCv. It offers a solution which asks me to ping an IP address, however when I do this I get another error which I also included in this question. Thanks for your help!

Here is the error

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's better to post this question on this community [Robotics.Stackexchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I solved it. I didn't have ssh installed on my ubuntu VMware fusion, so I checked it and reinstalled it. 

To reinstall it - sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Comment: Yes , both ends needs `SSH` properly installed to access and control the `ROS` things via multiple Linux terminals .

Answer (score 1):

This causes because of wrong configuration of `ros` parameters .

Check your `ros` parameter configuration on the VM

`Keep in mind that roscore and all other ros commands run without root permission`

```
 ### Configuring the parameter on VM ####
 export YOUR_VM_IP=192.168.7.2

 #setting ROS_MASTER_URI as VM's_ip ####
 export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.7.2:11311
```

If this not work manually add above the ROS parameters lines on `~/.bashrc` executing the following commands

```
 sudo vim ~/.bashrc

 sudo source ~/.bashrc

 sudo source ~/.profile
```

Also check my answer on [Robotics.Stackexchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com) for accessing master/remote ros notes correctly.

[How to call remote ROS node on mobile robot through laptop using wifi?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/11738/how-to-call-remote-ros-node-on-mobile-robot-through-laptop-using-wifi)

Also try this link [Setting up ROS on a virtual machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvjwhBqZkVM)

Hope this will somewhat help you !